# How to convert Electron's Main thread to something that will run on Android phone?

Tags: android, electron, fs

I have created an Electron application that runs on Desktop Windows and Linux.  The application uses the Main thread primarily to read/load files from the hard drive and transfer the data to the Renderer thread using shared memory (for speed).  My application loads, displays and animates 3D models.

I would now like to be able to run my application on an Android (and iOS) phone, but clearly I need to convert the Main thread to something else that can run locally on the phone.  I'd also need to re-work the communication between Main and Renderer to use sockets?

Any tips on how to convert an Electron App to something that will run on a phone?